# Why PostgreSQL shows times using comma as a decimal separator even if LC_NUMERIC is en_US.UTF-8

Tags: postgresql, psql

I run the following commands from the `psql` front-end. See how the time displayed at the end represents the decimal separator as a comma:

```
> \timing
Timing is on.
> show lc_numeric;
 lc_numeric  
-------------
 en_US.UTF-8
(1 row)

Time: 236,539 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because these query timings are formatted on the client side, inside psql. psql uses the locale set in your environment, not the database locale on the server.

When you launch psql, just set the appropriate locale in your environment:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
psql
```